# What is the difference between the two types of class constructors in PHP?

Tags: php, class, constructor

What exactly is the difference in PHP classes when using the `__construct` constructor and when using the name of the class as constructor?

For example:

```
class Some
{
     public function __construct($id)
     {
           ....
     }
     ....
}
```

OR

```
class Some
{
      public function Some($id)
      {
            ....
      }
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The top is the new way it is done in PHP as of version 5.0 and is how all new code should be written. The latter is the old PHP 4 way and is obsolete. At some point it will be completely deprecated and removed from PHP altogether.

**Update**

[As of PHP 5.3.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method as of PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Has already been deprecated in 5.3.3 according to [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). See Example #2

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will update my answer accordingly.